# How to exlude multi applications when implementing VPN?

Tags: android, vpn, tunnel, android-vpn-service

I am implementing VPN on my Android App.

I"m using this method to exlude proccess i don't want to go trow my tunnel :

```
builder.addDisallowedApplication(getPackageName());
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.android.settings");
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.android.server.appop");
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.android.systemui");
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.android.providers");
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.android");
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.android.server");
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.google.android.gms");
        builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.google.api");
```

and it goes on...

I Simply want all system apps to be exluded.

Is there a list somewere i can find?
Is there a way to use regex? for example :

```
builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.android.*");
```

What is the best practice to do it?